# drawCountour() not working

Tags: python, opencv

The `drawContour()` function is not working properly in Video frames. It is working for images by using this [stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475634/drawcontours-not-working-opencv-python). The output is just canny image without any contours drawn.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(frame,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1,kernel,iterations = 1)


    edges = cv2.Canny(erosion, 100 ,200)
    imCopy = edges.copy()

    laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(edges, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(laplacian,cv2.CV_8UC1, 0, 1, ksize=5)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sobely,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    frame = cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 3)
    cv2.imshow('window',frame)
    print len(contours)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k==27:
       break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Is `frame` RGB or grayscale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contours drawn will not be colored because you're drawing them on a single channel image. Here's how to draw colored ones. (Assuming `frame` is `BGR`. If the original `frame` is Grayscale, convert `frame_copy` in the code below to `BGR` using `cvtColor`).

```
_, frame = cap.read()
frame_copy = np.copy(frame)
.
.
.
cv2.drawContours(frame_copy, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('window',frame_copy)
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
frame = cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (255,0,0), 3)
cv2.imshow('window',frame)
```

Comment: it does show some output, But still doesn't show any contours drawn.

Comment: print len(contours) , it will print total no of contour detected

Comment: yes it does return an integer. Indicating that contours are drawn. But I am not able to view them. ( I have given blue color to image, but contours drawn are not colored.)

Comment: The same code is working , Please try again with the above modification and share your code ,if it dont work

Comment: I modified the code in the question. Can you please tell me why I am unable to view the blue coloured contours. I know that contours are being drawn because of len() function.